# How to measure the latency of messaging mechanism and extract the exact time for processing the messages by Masstransit and Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using `RabbitMq` with `Masstransit` to extchange messages in a distributed architecture and i really want to measure the impact of messaging mechanism on the latency of the  operation my applications are processing
any help ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonably modern answer would be to setup Open Telemetry, using something like Jaeger, and look at the measured results. [MassTransit has support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsTYClGrOVI) for OTEL, and you can see how using Jaeger makes it easy to view an entire transaction end-to-end.

You could perform similar timing comparisons with other approaches.

I will point out, it's a fun science project, but in the reality of applications that do more than:

`return Task.CompletedTask`

The difference between message-based solutions and RPC (such as HTTP APIs, etc.) are mostly insignificant compared to the benefits of durable asynchronous messaging.